# How can I express each of these quantifications in English?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

Let **T(x)** be the statement "***x has visited Tashkent***" where the domain consists of all students of my school. How  can I express each of these quantifications in English?

```
∃xT(x)
¬∃xT(x)
∃xT(x)
∀xT(x)
¬∀xT(x)
∀x¬T(x)
```

**EDIT:** Especially, the difference between ∃(∀)x¬T(x) and ¬∃(∀)xT(x)

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: I know about ∃xT(x) and ∀xT(x), they are pretty straightforward, but I have difficulty to distinguish ∃(∀)x¬T(x) and ¬∃(∀)xT(x). In the first case negation goes for premise and second case negation goes for quantifier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$T(x)=x$ has visited Tashkent.

$¬T(x)=x$ has not visited Tashkent.

> $∃xT(x)$ : There exist some $x$ who has visited Tashkent.
>
> $¬∃xT(x)=∀x¬T(x)$ :There exist no such $x$ who has visited Tashkent 'or' For all
> $x,x$ has not visited Tashkent.
>
> $∀xT(x)$ :For all $x,x$ has visited Tashkent.
>
> $¬∀xT(x)=∃x¬T(x)$ :For not all $x,x$ has visited Tashkent 'or' there exist some $ x$ who has not visited Tashkent.

Comment: Thank you, now I understand very well, actually it seems very easy now :)

Comment: Main tricks is,when you take the outer negation(¬) to inside then ∃ changes to ∀ and vice-versa